# How to have multiple c# classes in Microsoft visual studio express for web

Tags: c#, html, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Ok so ive made multiple c# programs before. I however don't have much experience with Microsoft visual studio express. I wanted to make an c# web program using old programs i made in c#. When i made a new project it make a c# file to be associated with the HTML file that was generated, how ever i don't know how to add multiple c# classes and/or files. For example a Node class, a list class, and then the main class that the c# that is associated with the HTML. Which is already generated when i made the HTML. Does anyone know what im talking about, or know how to do this, if it can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to right click your project name, in the solution explorer menu and select 'Add..' then select 'Class'.

If you're using multiple projects and would like to use classes from another project, simply right click the References folder and add a reference to an existing project.

I hope this helps

Comment: LOL, why didnt i think of that. Thanks. Do you know if i can use nodes and stuff?

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) Sure you can, just create separate classes

Comment: Yeah, however its a generic, and for some reason i guess express wants be to define <T> for every generic in my program... wow express annoys me.